# How to set the property of an yet-undefined element and create it on the fly?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var x = {}
x['hello'] = {"what": "world"}
alert(x['hello'].what)
```

works because the element 'hello' is explicitly set.

I would like to define a proerty of a yet-not set element and create it on the fly, something like

```
var x = {}
x['hello']['what'] = "world"
```

This fais with `TypeError: Cannot set property 'what' of undefined`.

**Is there a way to handle such a case, similarly to using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in Python?**

Comment: No, I don't think Javascript has this.

Comment: Good old Perlish autovivification. Not in Javascript. But why do you *really* need that?

Comment: What is the obsession with one-liners? Are we running out of newlines?

Comment: @Barmar. If that's the case, semicolon to the rescue!

Comment: @Thilo: it is useful to avoid creating nested boilerplate (empty) declarations just to have a placeholder.

Comment: You can make a function `$set` to do that and it becomes `$set(x, 'hello', value)`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit crude and can probably be improved upon, but as a start you could use a function which splits a . separated string and creates the nested sub objects for you. Something like this works

```
function setObjValue(obj, nesting, value) {
  var nestArr = Array.isArray(nesting) ? nesting : (nesting.indexOf(".") > -1) ? nesting.split(".") : [nesting],
      len = nestArr.length,            
      i = 0,
      cur = obj;

  for (; i < len; i++) {
    if (i === len-1) {
      cur[nestArr[i]] = value;
    } else {
      if (!cur[nestArr[i]]) cur[nestArr[i]] = {};
      cur = cur[nestArr[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

Then to use

```
var a = {};
setObjValue(a, "hello.what", "world");
//OR
setObjValue(a, ["hello", "what"], "world");
console.log(a); //{hello:{ what: "world" }};
```

**UPDATE:**
I've just updated the function above and the fiddle to handle objects with those keys already set and it will also accept the nesting argument as an array.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86b2nw4s/2/)

Comment: Nesting could be an array. `setObjValue(a, ["hello", "what"], "world");`

Comment: Yup could add a simple check and allow both scenarios, internally the string is split by . into an array anyhow so would be very simple. Mainly showing the OP an idea of where to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Object.setPrototypeOf(x, {"what": "world"})` . Does that work for you?

or using `Object.setPrototypeOf({}, {"hello": {"what": "world"}})` for the "hello" case.

Comment: by using Object.setPrototypeOf({}, {"hello": {"what": "world"}}), you can just go as deep as you want.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that it recreates the whole object every time. In other words, I cannot use it twice without overwriting the first entry

Comment: you can do if(!myObject) { //do my thing }. But ok, I tried :)

Comment: This is what I do to create the boilerplate - it gets more complicated when one cannot predict the number of levels in the object (`a.b.c.d` vs `a.b.c`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but note that support is not global.

There's also some edge cases that must be taken into account. Below is a very simple (and potentially naïve) implementation of a `defaultdict` in JS:

```js
function makeDefaultDictFor(obj) {
  // Protect against infinite recursion for
  // intentionally nonexistng properties
  let bannedKeys = [Symbol.toPrimitive, Symbol.iterator, "toJSON"];
  
  // Create a proxy that returns a new object for any missing keys.
  // The returned object also has the same behaviour, so you can
  // nest infinitely deep.
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, prop) => {
      if (bannedKeys.indexOf(prop) >= 0) return;
      
      // Return existing values when possible
      if (prop in target) return target[prop];
      
      // Make a proxy like this one for undefined keys.
      let newProxy = makeDefaultDictFor({});
      // Save the object as a property in this object.
      target[prop] = newProxy;
      
      return newProxy;      
    }
  });
}

let obj = makeDefaultDictFor({});
obj.hello.world = "!";
document.write("<pre>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
document.write("</pre>");
```